# How to create a child window is transparent and the parent window is not transparent？

Tags: c++, windows

I want to create a window with two child windows. Only the background of the top child window is transparent. I can directly see the background of the parent window and not the content of other child windows.Like the picture, A is parent, B is child 1, C is child 2.The background of child 2 is the same as parent.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t4eN.png)

Comment: Are you the using the MFC framework ?

Comment: @Rich I used a open source UI framework.

Comment: @weiqian: There's no code, you don't tell us which framework you use - how do you expect us to give you an answer?

Answer (score 0):

A-a-m,

You paint background on child window by yourself.
There is method OnPaint (in MFC) or message WM_PAINT.
And you should draw transparent background (it means to draw nothing).
Does it work?

If you use non-standart framework to create windows, you should specify background is painted programmatically.

Comment: The child window and parent window are not the same process.

Comment: "There are more things in heaven and Earth ..."; anyway: each ordinary window is painting its background by itself. And main window too. (in my opinion :( )

Answer (score 0):

A few options to experiment with:

If in your open source UI framework you can remove the WM_PAINT
    handler entry in the Def­Window­Proc then you could do that.

Handle the WM_PAINT message yourself and do nothing in the handler except clear any flag that indicates that the client area
    needs to be re-drawn. You'll need to find something equivalent to
    ValidateRect.

Both of these methods MIGHT cause non client areas like the window frame to  artifact within the client area as you move window C around but I can't be sure.